# Proof regarding restriction of an endomorphsim

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need help with the proof of this

**Theorem:** the restriction of an endomorphism $f:V\rightarrow V$ to a vector subspace $H \subset V$ such that $H$ is **invariant** is still an endomorphism:

$f|_{H}: H\rightarrow H$

such that $f|_{H}(x)=f(x)$ $\forall x \in H$.

Using the definition, the restriction of $f$ to $H$ should be
$f|_{H}:H \rightarrow V$

But since $f(H)\subset H$ can I conclude that

$f|_{H}:H \rightarrow V = f|_{H}:H \rightarrow H$ ?

If so, I can't understand the reason of that.

Moreover, considering a generic endomorphism $g$ is it possible to say that

$g: V\rightarrow V= g: V\rightarrow \operatorname{im}(g)$ ?

Am I missing something?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think that the question was posed to you in a manner that was ever so slightly sloppy. What they meant was that when the domain and codomain of $f$ are both shrunk to $H$, the resulting map $f|_H:H\to H$ is an endomorphism of $H$. You were completely correct to consider two maps that differ in nothing but their codomains to be different, but your text was not so fastidious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is clear now! Just a question, would this be valid also if $H$ is not invariant for $f$?

Comment: If $f(H)\not\subset H$ then of course there’s no endomorphism of $H$ to talk about. But maybe you were asking something else?